# Why do I get zero here? Assigning array elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, variables, numpy-ndarray

Why does this

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
a_old = a[0]
a[0] = a[0] + np.array([1,1,1])
print(a[0] - a_old)
```

give

```
[0 0 0]
```

and not

```
[1 1 1]
```

? But on the other hand

```
b = 2
b_old = b
b = b + 1
print(b - b_old)
```

gives indeed

```
1
```

as I would expect. I suppose there is a difference between assigning something to np.array elements, and assigning something to a variable. But I don't quite see through it. Thanks for help!

Comment: Try `print(a_old)` and you'll see.

Comment: That's because `type 'int'` is value type and `type 'list'` is reference type.

Comment: `a` is an array, and `a[0] = ...` modifies, or mutates that arrah.  `b` is an int, and `b=b+1` makes a new int, it does not modify `b` or `b_old`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be tricky in numpy! It's because that when you do `a_old = a[0]`, you are creating a [view](https://numpy.org/devdocs/glossary.html#term-view) of the data in `a`, not a copy of the data. To quote the [numpy indexing documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html):

> It must be noted that the returned array is a view, i.e., it is not a copy of the original, but points to the same values in memory as does the original array.

So when you add to the original array: `a[0] = a[0] + np.array([1,1,1])`, the "value" of `a_old` changes as well since `a_old` points to the same location in memory. If you want to create a copy, you can simply edit your code:

```
a_old = a[0].copy()
```

In your floating point example, `b_old = b` copies the value of `b` to a new point in memory, so `b` and `b_old` can be changed without affecting one another.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because in Python, as well as other programming languages, lists are Reference type. So, the value stored in `a[0]`, isn't the list but it's a memory address where the list is stored.

So, the instruction `a_old = a[0]`, copy the address of `a[0]` in `a_old`, and both the variables will reference the same list.

Instead, doing `b_old = b`, you're copying the value `2` directly.

To notice this, try running `print(a_old is a[0])`, you should see `True`.

Now, to solve your problem, you can run `a_old = a[0].copy()`.
After this, `print(a_old is a[0])` will output `False`, because the reference of the two variables are different.

Comment: `a` is a numpy array, not a list.  `a[0]` is a "row" of `a`, a `view` (not a reference as it would be with a list).   But the `copy()` step is right in either case.